# Batch file, looping through files and check existence based on extensions

Tags: loops, batch-file, file-extension

I am fairly new to batch files, so this might seem a bit noob-ish, but here it goes :)
I am trying to apply some procedures on files in a folder
- loop through all files in a folder, having no extension, or having the .csv extension
(this part I already figured out:

```
for %%i in (*.csv *.) do <command> %%i -s
```

But I want to skip this if I already have a %%i.txt file in that folder (i.e. - do the command only for files which do not have a corresponding .txt file int folder).
This is the part I can't quite figure out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this :

```
for %%i in (*.csv *.) do if not exist "%%~ni.txt" <command> %%i -s
```

Comment: It works for the files with no extension, but it fails for the *.csv. If the file.txt exists, it will still perform the command for file.csv

Answer (score 0):

It works with this:

```
for %%i in (*.csv *.) do if not exist "%%~ni.txt" <command> %%i -s
```

You need to use the substitution modifier **"~n"** to restrict the variable "i" to only the file name, and not the extension. More details here:
[MS Win XP Documentation](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/for.mspx?mfr=true)